# How to Register a device through Azure Notification Hub App Service SDK or manually for a Xamarin Forms App?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, azure-notificationhub

So i'm using Azure Notification Hub, and in that i followed their tutorial where they had mentioned to use FCM for Android , configure it and use their API key, and creating a certificate for iOS, which is working flawless

But the problem is i'm working on Xamarin forms, and i'd like to know if i could do the registration manually through API, and i've already written a method to do that in my API Service

```
 public async Task<string> RegisterDevice([FromBody] string handle = null)
    {
        string newRegistrationId = null;
        //newRegistrationId = await hub.CreateRegistrationIdAsync();
        //// make sure there are no existing registrations for this push handle (used for iOS and Android)
        //if (handle != null)
        //{
        //    var registrations = await hub.GetRegistrationsByChannelAsync(handle, 100);

        //    foreach (var registration in registrations)
        //    {
        //        if (newRegistrationId == null)
        //        {
        //            newRegistrationId = registration.RegistrationId;
        //        }
        //        else
        //        {
        //            await hub.DeleteRegistrationAsync(registration);
        //        }
        //    }
        //}
        newRegistrationId = await hub.CreateRegistrationIdAsync();
        return newRegistrationId;
    }
```

But i'm not able to understand how the device would be linked to this registration ID and/or what is a pns handle, i know the abbreviation but i dont know how to use it in this case or if at all is it necessary?
Any help would be deeply appreciated

Comment: What tutorial are you trying to follow?

Comment: Hi ,you can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/azure-services/azure-notification-hub) to set up Azure Notification Hubs .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Hi, thanks a lot for your reply,, but like i said, i have followed that tutorial already, but my question is would i be able to register to the hub on my own terms, like after a user logs in or something, by native code or by API? Because i don't want the user to get notifications when he's not logged into my app and i need to add a tag which would be his username

Comment: @Saamer The above one mentioned by Jiang

Comment: I think i see what you are asking- calling  `RegisterForRemoteNotifications();` (iOS) `CreateNotificationChannel();` (Android) after Login. What you're asking would require a few steps- You would have to created a DependencyService like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction and call it something like "IPushRegistrationService" that would basically be called after login. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Saamer yea I did the same thing for Android..working on iOS now but I'm not sure if that would be a good solution..if I could get to know how to do it using API then it would be a lot easier..

Comment: Likely is the best solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While registering [Azure Notification Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/azure-services/azure-notification-hub), If you want to ask for Push permissions after login, you have to call `RegisterForRemoteNotifications();` (iOS) & `CreateNotificationChannel();` (Android) after Login. 
What you're asking would require a few steps- 
You would have to created a DependencyService like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction), which would require creating an Interface like `IPushRegistrationService` with a `RegisterForPush()` function that would basically be called after login:

```
var pushService = DependencyService.Get<IPushRegistrationService>();
pushService.RegisterForPush();
```